# Double quotes do NOT preserve the newline character in shell script // Zenity

Tags: shell, newline, zenity

I use Tokland's youtube-upload to upload videos. I feed my script which does the upload with data that I copy+paste from a form textarea field into a zenity dialog (like title, description, etc.). That input gets split into single items. That all works well, except for the description, which is cut off after the first newline.

When I isolate the description with a single dialog, it works

```
description=$(zenity --entry --text "FEED ME" --title "Description" --entry-text="");
printf $description # print outs the description with newlines
```

Now I try it with a zenity --forms dialog, but again the description is cutoff.

```
unset IFS

multiInput=$(zenity --forms --title="Everything + Description" --text="ENTER DATA  \
    --add-entry="Everything" \
    --add-entry="Description");

printf "%s\n" "$multiInput" # prints out form input properly w/ linebreaks

IFS="$IFS|" read -ra ALLdesc <<< "$multiInput"

printf "${ALLdesc[1]}" # prints out only the first line
```

I read that enclosing a variable in "" should prevent this, but that does not work here.
Any idea about this?

Thanks,
SV

Answer (score 0):

By setting `IFS='|'` you are saying you want word splitting on the `|` character *only*.

Since you want to also retain newlines, you'll have to ensure `\n` is in the `IFS` as well. So, you should append `|` to `IFS` rather than overwriting it, e.g. `IFS="$IFS|"`.

Comment: like ```IFS="$IFS|" read -ra ALLdesc <<< "$multiInput"``` ?

Comment: Looks fine. Have you tried it? Is it not working?

Comment: Not really ... wenn I have the following:

`IFS="$IFS|" read -ra ALLdesc <<< "$multiInput"
printf "${ALLdesc[0]}\n\n"
printf "${ALLdesc[1]}\n\n"` then ${ALLdesc[0]} contains everything till the first space and ${ALLdesc[1]} everything till the second space

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. What shell are you using to run this? What input are you providing in the dialog? Another thing you can try is adding `unset IFS` at the start of the script, maybe its been set oddly in your environment.

Comment: Standard bash shell on MacOS 10.14.6. Unsetting IFS helped to remove that weird error before, now we are back where we started, the description is cut off after the first newline

Comment: SHFT∑(LP) (Qilla Records, QR079)∑125∑ SHFT QR079 Techno ContemporaryTechno Arcane∑ SHFT - Arcane√SHFT - Sphinx√SHFT - Hellkite√SHFT - Octane√SHFT - Raven√SHFT, Monophonik - X-Y√SHFT - Survivor√SHFT - Vortex√SHFT - Malicious√SHFT - Xenomorph∑Techno, Contemporary Techno, Raw Techno, SHFT, Arcane, LP) (Qilla Records, QR079, 2020, bandcamp.com, ∑SHFT - Arcane (LP) (Qilla Records, QR079)∑17:45√18:00√18:15√18:30√18:45√19:00√19:15√19:30√19:45√20:00∑2020-11-06|Support the label & the artist : https://shftin.bandcamp.com/album/arcane https://www.beatport.com/release/arcane/3172900

Comment: Above is the output of $multiInput. I use ∑ and √ as delimiter, which does the job. The description and second text input starts with the line: Support the label & the artist :, then comes the next line, and this is where the description is cut off.

Comment: It could be an issue with zenity itself on Mac, as I can't reproduce this on Linux. Can you update your question with the input you give and the output of of `$multiInput` to see if its as expected. Try `printf "%s\n" "$multiInput"` and see what that gives.

Comment: Yes, `printf "%s\n" "$multiInput"`produces the output like I want it (the complete description properly formatted with line breaks)